# Make RFC calls logging

Tags: logging, abap, saprfc

I would like to log each call of my RFC function module. What is the current state of the art in SAP/ABAP to do this?

Where do these logs get stored and how to see them? Or is it better to create a custom table and write the calls into this table?

ABAP version is 7.4

Answer (score 4):

There is a set of log transactions, notably SLG0 (to create transaction category) and SLG1 (to look at logs). A search on sap blogs about SLG1 will return useful links

To resume those :

- Modules functions BAL_LOG_* allow the creation/save of logs. Some usage exemple are present [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/04/18/create-and-view-log-using-slg0-and-slg1-transaction/)
- A log class created to simplify the usage of the log is described [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/09/30/show-scn-the-better-logger-i-promised/).

Comment: thank you for your hints. This is not against you, it is against the current situation. You say "A search on sap blogs about SLG1 will return useful links" I think blogs and docs are two different things. In sap world it seems to be common that the only useful docs are in blog posts. I am missing official docs from upstream (sap) which get maintained. Blog posts are often outdated since they don't get maintained. If you are I am currently writing down my experience learning abap here: https://github.com/guettli/why-i-like-django-and-sap

Comment: There are official docs for this [here](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70ehp2/helpdata/de/3a/c8263712c79958e10000009b38f936/frameset.htm).

Answer (score 3):

SAP has a [special framework](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/LOGGING_RFC_WEB_SERVICES/2.0/en-US) for enabling the RFC logging, it is called LOWGWIN (LOGCOM 200).

Feature set:

> The logging of RFCs allows you to establish which users had access to
> which data at what point in time. You can log data on RFC Function
> Module (FM) level, for example:
>
> - Type of parameters
> - Name and corresponding values of parameters
>
> In order to minimize the amount of logged data, you can do the following:
>
> - Restrict logging to certain users
> - Filter the parameters that need to be logged before they are included in the log records
> - Enable logging on client level only for the RFC Function Modules that
>   you want to log

You can fine-tune wich RFC calls (modules) will be logged including successful or failed ones by BAdI `/LOGWIN/BADI_RFC_LOG_FILTER`.

Initially the log is stored temporarily in SAP and can be viewed via transaction `/LOGWIN/SHOW_LOG`, after that you can transfer necessary log records to external repository (which you should set up in advance) by transaction `/LOGWIN/TSF_TO_EXT`.

Architecture overview:

[image]

More documentation is here:

- [Configuration guide](https://help.sap.com/viewer/091365037d3542a188d6df5869ee49c3/2.0/en-US), installation guide in [SAP Note 1870371](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1870371), installation is done from https://support.sap.com/swdc `> Software Downloads > Installations and Upgrades > A–Z Index > L > LOGGING OF RFC AND WEB SVCS 2.0`
- [Application guide](https://help.sap.com/viewer/942d33c2fbbc44919f85f83fb3bda779/2.0/en-US)